# Defrosting Fish without Bag

Tags: fish, frozen

So I am trying to defrost some frozen fish using running water, but I do not have a bag to place the fish in. If I just put the fish directly into running water without a bag and thaw it this way, will I die or get very sick?

Thanks.

Comment: Where in the World are you hat you can't find a plastic bag?

Comment: My apartment. I ran out of bags.

Comment: Walk out on street, find a plastic bag flying around, wash it, use that

Comment: That's gross, and seems more dangerous than my proposed method. Also, I live in LA, so doubly gross.

Comment: Well while you walk to the store, you can pick up the plastic bags, and put them in the rubbish. The water in LA is scarce, don't run it, just fill a bowl. Fish doesn't need much defrosting

Comment: It won't do much for the texture of your fish. You're better off thawing it in 4% brine, and I assume you can't get that out of a tap.

Comment: Why can't you thaw the fish in whatever it came out of the freezer in? Has to be a jar or something if it's not a plastic bag; just run that under the tap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fill a clean bowl with cold water.  Place in sink.  Place fish in bowl under the tap.  Turn on cold water so that it slowly trickles into the bowl. This is safe in the short term, or just until the fish is thawed.  Of course, a firmer fleshed fish will handle this better than, say, a skate wing or some thin flounder.  A plastic bag is basically irrelevant for safety.  It will not keep you from getting sick if the fish remains in the danger zone for enough time...that is, unless your fish is floating in contaminated water, which is probably unlikely in your situation.

Comment: You could put the bowl of water and fish into the fridge for safer (but slower) thawing, right?

Comment: I'm not dead! Yay!